# matplotlib subplot animation trouble

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I'm trying to basically code multiple random walks into my python code, I've been using the brownian motion scipy page as a starting point. I know I'm basically making a mistake in the updating of each random walk array in `def updateData()`.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from scipy.stats import norm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot


def brownian(x0, n, dt, delta, out=None):

    x0 = np.asarray(x0)

    r = norm.rvs(size=x0.shape + (n,), scale=delta*sqrt(dt))    

    if out is None:
        out = np.empty(r.shape)

    np.cumsum(r, axis=-1, out=out)

    out += np.expand_dims(x0, axis=-1)

    return out

x = numpy.empty((2,N+1))
x[:, 0] = 0.0

f0 = figure()
ax01 = subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))

p011, = ax01.plot([],[],'b-')
p012, = ax01.plot([],[],'g-')

arr = []
def updateData(self):
    global yo
    global br


    for i in range(0,2):
        br = brownian(x[:,0], 10, 1, 0.25, out=None)
        arr.append(br)

    p011.set_data(arr[0])
    p012.set_data(arr[1])
    return p011,p012

simulation = animation.FuncAnimation(f0, updateData, 
                                     blit=False, frames=200, 
                                     interval=20000, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

If I write following loop outside `updateData`:

```
arr = []
for i in range(0,2):
    br = brownian(x[:,0], 10, 1, 0.25, out=None)
    arr.append(br)
```

, I get the correct arrays for each random walk (`arr[0]`, and `arr[1]`), however I am having a lot of trouble actually getting these to work in a subplot animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you keep `append`'ing your new random walks to the array `arr`but you always plot the same results (namely `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`)
if you want to plot the latest results you should use:

```
def updateData(frame):
    for i in range(0,2):
        br = brownian(x[:,0], 10, 1, 0.25, out=None)
        arr.append(br)

    p011.set_data(arr[-2])
    p012.set_data(arr[-1])
    return p011,p012
```

EDIT: here is the full code that seem to be doing what you want

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import *
from scipy.stats import norm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
from JSAnimation.IPython_display import display_animation

def brownian(x0, n, dt, delta, out=None):
    x0 = np.asarray(x0)
    r = norm.rvs(size=x0.shape + (n,), scale=delta*sqrt(dt))    
    if out is None:
        out = np.empty(r.shape)
    np.cumsum(r, axis=-1, out=out)
    out += np.expand_dims(x0, axis=-1)
    return out

N=1
x = np.empty((2,N+1))
x[:, 0] = 0.0

f0 = figure()
ax01 = subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
ax01.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax01.set_ylim(-2,2)
p011, = ax01.plot([],[],'b-')
p012, = ax01.plot([],[],'g-')

arr = []
def updateData(self):
    for i in range(0,2):
        br = brownian(x[:,0], 100, 1, 0.25, out=None)
        arr.append(br)

    p011.set_data(arr[-2])
    p012.set_data(arr[-1])
    return p011,p012

simulation = animation.FuncAnimation(f0, updateData, blit=False, frames=200, interval=500, repeat=False)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for reply. Your answer makes sense, but when I try running my code I get this error;

if self._size is not None and self._size > 1:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Hey, maybe I'm not fully describing my problem (or else I'm just confusing myself). My arr is an array containing two 2x(N+1) arrays. One for each random walk. 

The 2x(N+1) array represents the x and y co-ordinate (the 2) at each time step (N+1) of the random walk. 

I want my updateData() function to be able to continuously update the last x-y co-ordinate of each random walk, so both can be displayed together on the animation.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the full code. As far as I understand, this does what you want.
What I'm not clear about is whether you want to plot a new pair of random walks on each frame (that's what the code is doing) or if you want to add more steps to the random walk already started before?

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the reply. I just tried running your code, and it's not what I want the output to be. The code is generating two random walks, and plotting every data point in one animation, and then restarting. 

I want the animation to be a video of the random walk progression from time t0 to tN . It will look like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2PbqzaLYCo but I want to be able to have two random walks on the same video (I am trying to do with with the for loop)